# Kill adb server using perl script

Tags: perl, adb

I am trying to kill the adb server after running my script. I have a subroutine called terminate which I use to stop the script and kill ad server.

```
         sub terminate
   {
      print "\nTerminating script ...\n";
      system("adb kill-server");
      if($ostype eq 'MSWin32') {
      $ProcessObj->Kill(0);
    }
      exit 0;
}
```

I am getting an error saying "Can't call method "Kill" on an undefined value". I looked up in my script and found that scalar $ProcessObj is defined but I haven't used it besides in this subroutine. How can I get past this issue, need to fix this asap. Thanks

Comment: Have you assigned any values to $ProcessObj? Do you have `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the beginning of your script?  These will help debug issues like this

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work, the problem was that the adb was not restarting gracefully. Just added 
system("adb start-server")